# recommended pc build for dedicated game streaming

Tags: pc

I am building a PC that will be dedicated to game streaming. It will be a secondary PC and it's entire function will be to accept the input from my gaming PC, encode it and upload it to streaming services.

I want to use OBS and stream at 1080p 60fps.

I am thinking of going with:-

Ryzen 1700,
8gb 3200mhz ram (whatever is cheapest),
WD Blue 3TB hard disk (stream will also be saved to disk),
ASRock AB350M motherboard

All of that comes to around £450 on Amazon uk.

Is that powerful enough to stream at 1080p 60fps, Is it the best hardware choice for the money spend and if it's not what would be better in the same price range.

Comment: this is clearly not off topic, asking for hardware recommendations before purchase to achieve a particular goal is exactly what this question is doing.

Comment: Yeah, I don't feel this is off-topic either.  Many other questions of this nature are way more broad, and allowed to stay open.